# Can't assign a google maps map to custom view

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

So I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map?hl=sv#add_a_map) on how to add a Google map to an iOS application and it all works fine. But what I want to do is assign the map, not to `self.view` but a custom view I dragged out on to the storyboard inside(?) the other view, because when adding the map to `self.view` I can't add other elements, like buttons, or well, I probably can but I don't know how.

Code:

```
// Start locationmanager
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// Set up the startposition for the camera when the app first starts.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.34702 longitude:18.04053 zoom:10];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
self.view = mapView_;
```

So i created a `UIView` inside the view currently containing the map and ctrl dragged it to create an outlet called mapView in that `viewController`. So i changed the line of code from

```
self.view = _mapView;
```

to

```
self.mapView = _mapView;
```

but this does not seem to work at all, just blank. Both `self.view` and `self.mapsView` are instances of `UIView`, so why does this not work?

Update:

This is what my viewDidLoad looks like atm:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.mapView addSubview:mapView_];

// Start locationmanager
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// Standard cameraposition
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.34702 longitude:18.04053 zoom:10];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.frame camera:camera];


self.mapView = mapView_;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your project:

```
//
//  testViewController.m
//  maps
//
//  Created by Millén on 2013-02-25.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 JamWeb. All rights reserved.
//

#import "testViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface testViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *gMapView;
@end

@implementation testViewController {
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
}

-(void)loadView
{
    CLLocationDegrees lat = 59.34702;
    CLLocationDegrees lon = 18.04053;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon zoom:10];
    self.gMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.gMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = self.gMapView;

    [self updateLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Start locationmanager
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}

- (IBAction)updateLocation {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    /*
    if(!oldLocation)
    {
        oldLocation = location;
    }

    if (![location isEqual:oldLocation]) {
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude
                                                                longitude: location.coordinate.longitude
                                                                     zoom:7];

        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        self.view = mapView_;

        oldLocation = location;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
     */



    NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I think this would still have the "base view" as the view using the map. That is not the current issue anymore. See the comments on the original post if you are interested. Thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 11):

Do the following:

1. Change your custom view Class to `GMSMapView` in the identity inspector of IB
2. create outlet `mapView` to this custom view in you view controller (pay attention that outlet type is also `GMSMapView`)

So now when you start your app this instance  will be created, and it will display default location on the map (near London). Now you only need to create a camera and add it to the map object. Add this code in your ViewDidLoad method:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:45.24 longitude:19.84 zoom:6]; 
// set camera location to Novi Sad, Serbia :-)

[self.mapView setCamera:camera];     // set the camera to map
```

Thats it, you do not need instance variable `mapView_` from Google sample code, nor any other code from Google sample. Enjoy!

Comment: Bonus points for stating that the instance variable isn't needed anymore, that the custom view takes its place. Once I removed and adjusted all reference to that, I got my custom view to accept gMap methods. And since it's a `@property` declaration, no need for instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

CGRectZero will make its size zero.  You should use self.mapView.frame instead.

Also need to add add mapView_ as subview of mapView:

```
[self.mapView addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: Tried this, see my update on the original post for my code. Sadly, no difference.